# asking for an input without stopping a while loop python 3.4.3

Tags: python-3.x

all i need to do is find out how to do this specific thing as you see my code is fine but while it is counting down i want to ask for an input to cancel or stop the countdown so an input is required without stopping everything else

```
import time
def check(n):
    try:
        int(n)
    except ValueError:
        print("thats not a number \n")
        restart()
        return False
    else:
        int(n)
print("welcome to the countdown")
def miniutes():
    mini = input("how many minutes would like to count down:")
    check(mini)
    mini = int(mini)
    global mini
    while mini > 60:
          print("sorry you cannot have over 60 miniutes")
          mini = input("how many minutes would like to count down:")
          check(mini)
          mini = int(mini)
def seconds():
    sec = input("how many seconds would like to count down:")
    check(sec)
    sec = int(sec)
    global sec
    while sec > 60:
          print("sorry you cannot have over 60 seconds")
          sec = input("how many seconds would like to count down:")
          check(sec)
          sec = int(sec)
def restart():
    print("please input 2 numbers the first one in minutes the second in seconds")
    miniutes()
    seconds()
restart()
options = ["1.cancel","2.pause"]
tim = [mini,sec]
while tim[0]+tim[1] >  0:
    print("\n"100)
    print(tim)
    print(options)
    time.sleep(1)
    tim[1] -= 1
    if tim[1] < 0:
        if tim[0] >= 1:
            tim[0] -= 1
            tim[1] = 59
    elif tim[0]+tim[1] < 1:
        print("\n"100)
        print(tim)
        print("\ntimer done")
```

this is a school project so i can only use the modules that come with python 3.4.3

i tried using multi threading and it didn`t work as it started waiting for me to enter anything for it to print the timer again